# Is it possible to make a file created by my app unmodifiable

Tags: java, android

My app creates files. Now, I save the name of these filename in SharedPreferences, and query the folder to get the files by the names stored in SharedPreferences. If someone goes to the folder and changes the name of a file, then that will be lost, as the new name will not be contained within my SharedPreferences, and hence I'll not be able to query it, to show it within my app. So, is there a way to make a file unmodifiable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create the files you do not want changed in your application's private data folder. Other applications and users do not have permission to modify those files.

To access your private folder:

```
File file = new File(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir(), "filename");
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getFilesDir()

These files will be deleted if your app is uninstalled.

Comment: How do I create files in the private folder? Also, will deleting the app delete the data in the private folder?

Comment: I'm currently creating files this way - `String filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
        File file = new File(filepath, NEWFOLDER);`

Comment: In what order will the files be sorted?

Comment: I'm unsure what you mean by sorted.